# FileUpload isFormField() returning true when submitting file

Tags: java, html, jsp, http, servlets

I am using `Apache-Commons FileUpload library` to upload files to a server. It was working fine, but suddenly when I am submitting the file, `FileItem.isFormField()` is returning true for some reason or another. This is the code I have

**FileUpload.java** servlet

```
if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) 
{
    List<FileItem> items = new ServletFileUpload(
                   new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);

    for (FileItem item : items)
    {
        // if item is a file type and not a form field 
        if (!item.isFormField())
        {
                // UPLOAD FILE
        }
    }
}
```

**ticketform.jsp**

```
<form action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method=post>
    <button type="button" id="clip-btn" class="attach-tool-tip" >
        <img src="images/attachment.png" id="attach-img" width="25px"/>
    </button>

    <input id="attach-btn" type="file" style="display:none"/>
    <input id="submit-form" name="upload" type="submit" style="display:none"/>
</form>
```

**ticketform.js**

```
// trigger file chooser click when clicking paper clip icon
$('#clip-btn').click(function()
{
    $('#attach-btn').trigger('click');
});

// trigger file submit on filename change in input type='file'
$('#attach-btn').change(function()
{
    $('#submit-form').trigger('click');
});
```

When I am seeing the contents of '`attach-btn`' i.e. the input file type, the file is there with it's correct name, last modified, size etc.. so it is submitting with the good file. Can there be any external reason why when the request is parsed, it's counting as a form field?

Comment: can you please run with the display of the file field not to be hidden, and tell us if it is still not working?

Comment: I removed the file field from being hidden and used it instead. I noticed that the page is being refreshed another time i.e. another request is being submitted but I can't figure out from where

Comment: try adding this code: $("#submit-form").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$('#myform').submit();
});

Comment: and add the id='myform' attribute to your form. This will submit the form only once

Comment: It is submitting twice because the type of button is `submit`. This will submit the form once it is clicked, and once in the handler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it's a typo but you are missing a "name" attribute, wich is mandatory.

```
<input id="attach-btn" type="file" name="someFile" style="display:none"/>
```

After some testing, without a name in the field, the `file input` is not included in the `List<FileItem>`. You recieve just the `submit input` with a default value (in my case something like "send request").

Try it and tell us if it worked.

Comment: yes it worked! thanks a lot @Nefreo! I didn't know the name was mandatory since I wasn't using it directly!

Comment: You could switch the "upload" name from the submit to the file input. The name is mandatory for a "successfull control" on a form. See [The W3C Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls). Glad that helped!