# Uploading jar to nexus with Spring RestTemplate

Tags: spring, nexus, resttemplate, apache-commons-fileupload

I would like to use Spring's RestTemplate to upload a jar to nexus. I found instructions on how to do it using curl [here](https://support.sonatype.com/entries/22189106-How-can-I-programatically-upload-an-artifact-into-Nexus-), which works just fine. However I have utterly failed in converting this to a RestTemplate call. Here is my code:

```
    String auth = "admin:admin123";
    byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64( auth.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")) );
    String authHeader = "Basic " + new String( encodedAuth );

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> files = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    files.add("r", "releases");
    files.add("hasPom", "false");
    files.add("e", "jar");
    files.add("g", "com.test.proj");
    files.add("a", "my-artifact");
    files.add("v", "1.0.0");
    files.add("p", "jar");
    files.add("file", new ByteArrayResource(jarBytes));

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
    headers.set("Authorization", authHeader);
    HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> entity = new HttpEntity<>(files, headers);
    String response = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/content", entity, String.class);
```

This fails with a `400 Bad Request`. After looking at [the source](http://www.massapi.com/source/github/18/05/180551976/plugins/restlet1x/nexus-restlet1x-plugin/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/rest/artifact/AbstractArtifactPlexusResource.java.html), it looks like my file is failing this key check:

```
 for (FileItem fi : files) {
    if (fi.isFormField()) {
      // parameters are first in "nibble"
      processFormField(request, uploadContext, fi);
    }
    else {
      // a file, this means NO parameters will income anymore
      // we either received all the GAVs as params, or we have a POM to work with (file1)
      ...
```

FileItem.isFormField is from Apache Commons FileUpload. **Does anyone know how I could get this to succeed with my "file" that I am passing in?**

In another question ([FileUpload isFormField() returning true when submitting file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945201/fileupload-isformfield-returning-true-when-submitting-file)) the answer suggests that I need a name field, or perhaps in my case, the "type" doesn't come through. **If this is the case, is it possible to specify these while making a post request?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that this currently isn't possible with RestTemplate. I opted to use Apache's HttpComponents, which has worked wonderfully. Here is the resulting code:

```
public void uploadToNexus(String version, File myJar, String artifactId)
{
    try(CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault())
    {
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://admin:admin123@mydomain:8081/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/content");

        FileBody jarFileBody = new FileBody(myJar);

        HttpEntity requestEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
                .addPart("r", new StringBody("releases", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
                .addPart("hasPom", new StringBody("false", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
                .addPart("e", new StringBody("jar", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
                .addPart("g", new StringBody("com.domain.my", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
                .addPart("a", new StringBody("my-artifactId", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
                .addPart("v", new StringBody(version, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
                .addPart("p", new StringBody("jar", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
                .addPart("file", jarFileBody)
                .build();

        httpPost.setEntity(requestEntity);

        try(CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost))
        {
            logger.info("response from nexus: {}", response.toString());
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to close the httpClient", e);
    }
}
```

I needed the following maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```